# Multiple instances of a JavaScript carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

So I have the following code I have written to build a carousel in JavaScript using `Hammer.js` and `jQuery`:

```
var hCarousel = {

    container: false,
    panes: false,
    pane_width: 0,
    pane_count: 0,
    current_pane: 0,

    build: function( element ) {

        hCarousel.container = $(element).find('.hcarousel-inner-container');

        hCarousel.panes = $(hCarousel.container).find('> .section');

        hCarousel.pane_width = 0;
        hCarousel.pane_count = hCarousel.panes.length;

        hCarousel.current_pane = 0;

        hCarousel.setPaneDimensions( element );

        $(window).on('load resize orientationchange', function() {

            hCarousel.setPaneDimensions( element );

        });

        $(element).hammer({ drag_lock_to_axis: true })
                    .on('release dragleft dragright swipeleft swiperight', hCarousel.handleHammer);

    },

    setPaneDimensions: function( element ){

        hCarousel.pane_width = $(element).width();

        hCarousel.panes.each(function() {
            $(this).width(hCarousel.pane_width);
        });

        hCarousel.container.width(hCarousel.pane_width*hCarousel.pane_count);

    },

    next: function() {

        return hCarousel.showPane(hCarousel.current_pane+1, true);

    },

    prev: function() {

        return hCarousel.showPane(hCarousel.current_pane-1, true);

    },

    showPane: function( index ) {

        // between the bounds
        index = Math.max(0, Math.min(index, hCarousel.pane_count-1));
        hCarousel.current_pane = index;

        var offset = -((100/hCarousel.pane_count)*hCarousel.current_pane);

        hCarousel.setContainerOffset(offset, true);

    },

    setContainerOffset: function( percent, animate ) {

        hCarousel.container.removeClass("animate");

        if(animate) {
            hCarousel.container.addClass("animate");
        }

        if(Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
            hCarousel.container.css("transform", "translate3d("+ percent +"%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1)");
        }
        else if(Modernizr.csstransforms) {
            hCarousel.container.css("transform", "translate("+ percent +"%,0)");
        }
        else {
            var px = ((hCarousel.pane_width*hCarousel.pane_count) / 100) * percent;
            hCarousel.container.css("left", px+"px");
        }

    },

    handleHammer: function( ev ) {

        ev.gesture.preventDefault();

        switch(ev.type) {

            case 'dragright':
            case 'dragleft':
                // stick to the finger
                var pane_offset = -(100/hCarousel.pane_count)*hCarousel.current_pane;
                var drag_offset = ((100/hCarousel.pane_width)*ev.gesture.deltaX) / hCarousel.pane_count;

                // slow down at the first and last pane
                if((hCarousel.current_pane == 0 && ev.gesture.direction == Hammer.DIRECTION_RIGHT) ||
                    (hCarousel.current_pane == hCarousel.pane_count-1 && ev.gesture.direction == Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT)) {
                    drag_offset *= .4;
                }

                hCarousel.setContainerOffset(drag_offset + pane_offset);

                break;

            case 'swipeleft':
                hCarousel.next();
                ev.gesture.stopDetect();
                break;

            case 'swiperight':
                hCarousel.prev();
                ev.gesture.stopDetect();
                break;

            case 'release':
                // more then 50% moved, navigate
                if(Math.abs(ev.gesture.deltaX) > hCarousel.pane_width/2) {
                    if(ev.gesture.direction == 'right') {
                        hCarousel.prev();
                    } else {
                        hCarousel.next();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    hCarousel.showPane(hCarousel.current_pane, true);
                }
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

And I call this like:

```
var hSections;

$(document).ready(function(){

    hSections = hCarousel.build('.hcarousel-container');

});
```

Which works fine. But I want to make it so that I can have multiple carousels on the page which again works... but the overall width of the container is incorrect because it's combining the width of both carousels.

How can I run multiple instances of something like this, but the code know WHICH instance it's interacting with so things don't become mixed up, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would try turning it into a function which you can use like a class. Then you can create separate objects for your carousels.

So you would have something like the following:

```
function HCarousel (element) {
    this.element=element;
    this.container= false;
    this.panes= false;
    this.pane_width= 0;
    this.pane_count= 0;
    this.current_pane= 0;
}
```

And then add each method on the class like this.

```
HCarousel.prototype.build = function() {
    this.container = $(element).find('.hcarousel-inner-container');
    this.panes = $(hCarousel.container).find('> .section');
    this.pane_width = 0;
    this.pane_count = hCarousel.panes.length;
    this.current_pane = 0;
    this.setPaneDimensions( element );
    $(window).on('load resize orientationchange', function() {
        this.setPaneDimensions( element );
    });
    $(this.element).hammer({ drag_lock_to_axis: true }).on('release dragleft dragright swipeleft swiperight', hCarousel.handleHammer);
};
```

etc. That should give you the basic idea. Will take a little bit of re-writing, but then you can create a carousel with something like this:

```
var carousel1 = new HCarousel('.hcarousel-container');
```

Hope that puts you on the right track.

Classes don't actually exist in JS, but this is a way to simulate one using a function. Here's a good article on using classes in JS http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your design is not really suited to multiple instances, because of the object literal which has properties of the carousel, but also the build method.

If I was starting this from scratch, I would prefer a more OOP design, with a carousel class that can you instantiate, or have it as a jQuery plugin. That said, it's not impossible to adapt your existing code.

```
function hCarousel(selector){
  function hCarouselInstance(element){
    var hCarousel = {

        // insert whole hCarousel object code
        container: false,
        panes: false,
        build : function( element ){
        ...

    };

    this.hCarousel = hCarousel;
    hCarousel.build(element);
  }

  var instances = [];
  $(selector).each(function(){
    instances.push(new hCarouselInstance(this));
  });

  return instances;
}
```

### Usage

For example, all elements with the `hcarousel-container` class will become an independant carousel.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var instances = hCarousel('.hcarousel-container');
});
```

### Explanation:

The `hCarousel` function is called passing the selector, which can match multiple elements. It could also be called multiple times if needed.

The inner hCarouselInstance is to be used like a class, and instantiated using the `new` keyword. When hCarousel is called, it iterates over the matched elements and creates a new instance of hCarouselInstance.
Now, hCarouselInstance is a self contained function that houses your original hCarousel object, and after creating the object it calls `hCarousel.build()`.

The `instances` return value is an array containing each instance object. You can access the `hCarousel` properties and methods from there, such as:

```
instances[0].hCarousel.panes;
```

---

### jQuery plugin

Below is a conversion to a jQuery plugin, which will work for multiple carousels.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.hCarousel = function( ) {
        return this.each(function( ) {

            var hCarousel = {
                // insert whole hCarousel object code here - same as in the question
            };

            hCarousel.build(this);

        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Plugin usage:

```
$('.hcarousel-container').hCarousel();
```

Comment: How easy would it be to move into a jQuery plugin?

Comment: @Cameron added a jQuery plugin conversion to the answer.